# How to get AWS account/service cost using CloudWatch API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, billing

I am aware that in order to get the detailed cost of an AWS account, I need to enable programmatic billing access and push the billing report to an S3 bucket in the respective AWS account.

This approach works fine for me. However, the problem is the bill size to be downloaded and processed is huge to just get the account and service-level cost of all linked AWS accounts for the past months.

I am trying to explore the AWS CloudWatch APIs to get the linked account level cost. I am trying to get the list of all linked accounts and the services being consumed by them using the following command:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "AWS/Billing"
```

which works exactly as expected and returns the result correctly. However, when trying to get the cost of these accounts using the following command:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace "AWS/Billing"
--dimensions "Name=LinkedAccount,Value=<linked-account-id>" --metric-name=EstimatedCharges --start-time=2017-10-01T19:30:00Z --end-time=2017-10-10T19:30:00Z --period=3600 --statistics=Sum
```

I get an almost empty JSON of the following form:

```
{
    "Datapoints": [],
    "Label": "EstimatedCharges"
}
```

I have ensured that I am using the right linked account ID and the other parameters being provided are as it is mentioned above. What am I missing here to get the account or service level costs?

**Edit 1:** I have set the region in my config file to us-east-1 since the region is a mandatory field for the commands to work. Is this somehow the cause? If yes, what is the fix/workaround?

**Update 1:** I am able to get the overall AWS account cost (primary account cost + linked account cost), using the above API, by just tweaking the dimensions, but am still not able to get the individual account/service cost (individual costs of primary and linked accounts).

**Update 2:** I am able to get linked account cost when I use an IAM user from the account whose cost I need. However, the `LinkedAccount` dimension is still not working: When I use the primary account's IAM user to get the cost of its linked accounts using the `LinkedAccount` dimension, it still returns an empty result. My expectation was, since I can get the linked accounts' costs in the bills of the primary account and I can see the linked accounts' costs when I log into AWS portal, I should be able to get the linked accounts' costs using the CloudWatch APIs. Still trying to get a solution for getting linked accounts' costs using the primary account's IAM user using CW APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Under Billing Preferences you can enable Programmatic access,

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/

> Billing --> S3(Trigger) CSV File --> Lambda --> S3(Billing for
>   specific accounts)

You can get alert to lambda and process the generated csv file for all linked accounts.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

If you want to perform poll for those charges,

> aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name EstimatedCharges
>   --start-time 2017-04-08T23:18:00 --end-time 2017-04-09T23:18:00 --period 3600 --namespace AWS/Billing --statistics Sum --dimensions Name=LinkedAccount,Value=accountid --dimensions
>   Name=Currency,Value=USD

You need to mention additional currency dimension too.

If cloudwatch does not have any data, you will not get any results.

Here is result I got for the linked account,

```
{
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-04-09T06:00:00Z", 
            "Sum": 70.34, 
            "Unit": "None"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-04-09T22:00:00Z", 
            "Sum": 76.4, 
            "Unit": "None"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-04-09T10:00:00Z", 
            "Sum": 73.37, 
            "Unit": "None"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-04-09T14:00:00Z", 
            "Sum": 73.37, 
            "Unit": "None"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-04-09T02:00:00Z", 
            "Sum": 70.34, 
            "Unit": "None"
        }, 
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-04-09T18:00:00Z", 
            "Sum": 76.4, 
            "Unit": "None"
        }
    ], 
    "Label": "EstimatedCharges"
}
```

Comment: No this is NOT what I am looking for. I have mentioned I am aware of the procedure of getting the cost from the bills dumped in the S3 bucket. I need an API that gives me the cost of the account and its services without downloading and processing these bills.

Comment: Nope, even after specifying the currency and linked account dimensions, I still get an empty JSON as posted in the question.

Comment: You may not have data for that time period. I have updated with results too.

Comment: Can you tell me what permissions have you assigned to the key-pair you are using to get these results?

Comment: Administrator Profile. If I use a profile that does not has permissions, then it gives empty results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156448/discussion-between-jobin-and-kannaiyan).